# can you dry hop in the primary, or do you have to rack into a secondary in order to add the dry hops?

Tags: dry-hop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should dry hopping be done in secondary, when to transfer, and for how long?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/6485/should-dry-hopping-be-done-in-secondary-when-to-transfer-and-for-how-long)

All this talk about primary vs secondary, and contamination, oxidation, makes it a little apprehensive to rack into a secondary for the purposes of dry hopping. That's why I'd like to know is it cool ti dry hop the primary, or do we have go secondary?

Comment: http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1792/dry-hopping-without-secondary-fermentation

Comment: http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/6485/should-dry-hopping-be-done-in-secondary-when-to-transfer-and-for-how-long

Answer (score 1):

Consider that commerical breweries regularly dry hop in primary, post-ferment.  You might get better results dry-hopping in a temp-controlled secondary or in keg (lower temps, less O₂, &c.), but there's no problem with dry-hopping in primary.

Answer (score 1):

I just dry hopped in primary yesterday and plan to bottle the same in 5 days. You can really dry hop whenever you like, but I would recommend doing it when fermentation has either slowed or almost completed, and do it in your final fermentation vessel (i.e. if you are doing secondary anyway, dry hop there instead). There is also other good input on this in other questions already asked, such as https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/a/1794/2518.

Answer (score 0):

I always dry-hop in the primary.  Mostly because I'm lazy, but also because of the reasons you mention: less chance of infection and oxidation.

If you prefer to secondary for clearer beer, that's an argument for dry hopping in the primary as well - you'll leave all that extra hop material in the primary instead of having to rack to a third vessel.

There is no compelling reason to move to the secondary for dry-hopping, especially since you're only dry-hopping a week or two: autolysis isn't an issue.

Comment: BTW, thanks to all.that responded with knowledge.